# Matrix optimization - sum of largest element in each column

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Feel free to tweek particular expressions if it will make it easier to find a solution. In the end, I will end up with an approximate anyway:

$V$ is a ***given*** $N\text{ x }m$ complex matrix with columns $v_j$.

$W$ is an $N\text{ x }n$ complex matrix with columns $w_i$. The problem has two variations, you may select whichever you like / think will be easier:

- Default: Columns of $W$ are unit norm, $||w_i||=1$
- Each element in $W$ is unit magnitude.

I want to find $W$ that maximizes the following with *as few columns as possible*, i.e. $n$ is small:

$$\sum_{j}\max_i(|w_i^Hv_j|) \leq\sum_{j}\max_i(|\frac{v_i^H}{||v_i^H||}v_j|)= \sum_{j}\frac{v_j^H}{||v_j^H||}v_j= \sum_{j}||v_j||$$

Left side of the inequality is  equivalent to $\text{sum of the biggest element in each column of }|W^HV|$

For a sense of scale, the dimensions are on the order of $N=10, m=1000, n=100$. If $W$ had as many columns as $V$, one could guarantee the perfect solution ($W$ is equal to $V$ with normalized columns). The tricky part is, I want to see how close I can get to the perfect solution when $n<m$.

Ultimately, I need to be able to look at any given $V$ and have a sense of how many columns $W$ needs to have to maximize the above expression *sufficiently*, where *sufficiently* means the summation above adds up to 90% of the perfect solution, that is when $W$ equals column normalized $V$. The more *complicated* $V$ is, the more columns $W$ would require. Some heuristic rough estimate is useful too.

This problem sort of kind of resembles the facility location problem, but that doesn't deal with complex numbers. Whatever solution I find, should be insensitive to a flat phase shift, since I care about the absolute value. What sort of approach would work for this?

Comment: First do the maximization "perfectly", resulting in optimal objective value V. Then minimize the number of columns subject to the additional constraint that the original objective $ \ge 0.9V$.